# In PaperJS rotating a shape around point is not working properly

Tags: javascript, canvas, vector-graphics, paperjs

I am trying to recreate the game Asteroids. This is a sample of the code for the Ship object constructor (I am using a constructor function and not an object literal because `this` doesn't work properly when referring to variables in a literal):

```
function Ship(pos) {
    var position = pos ? pos : view.center;
    var segments = [
            new Point(position) + new Point(0, -7.5), // Front of ship
            new Point(position) + new Point(-5, 7.5), // Back left
            new Point(position) + new Point(0, 3.5), // Rear exhaust indentation
            new Point(position) + new Point(5, 7.5) // Back right
        ]
    this.shipPath = new Path.Line({
        segments: segments,
        closed: true,
        strokeColor: '#eee',
        strokeWidth: 2
    });
    this.velocity = new Point(0, -1);
    this.steering = new Point(0, -1);
    this.rot = function(ang) {
        this.steering.angle += ang;
        this.shipPath.rotate(ang, this.shipPath.position);
    }
    this.drive = function() {
        this.shipPath.position += this.velocity;
    }
}

var ship = new Ship();

var path = new Path({
    strokeColor: '#ddd',
    strokeWidth: 1
});

function onFrame(event) {
    path.add(ship.shipPath.position);
    ship.drive();
}
```

I've left out the key handlers which is how the ship is steered, but basically what they do is call the `this.rot()` function with different angles depending whether the right or left buttons were clicked.

Basically my problem is that according to this, when steering the ship, the ship should rotate around its `shipPath.position`, which would leave that point travelling in a straight line as the ship revolves around it. Instead this is happening:

[image]

The curly bit in the `path` is from when I continuously steered the ship for a few seconds. Why is this happening? If the ship is revolving around its `position`, why should the position judder sideways as the ship rotates?

<s>Here is a link to where I've got this working on my own website: http://aronadler.com/asteroid/
I would have loved to put this on jsbin or codepen but despite hours work I have never been able to actually get the paperscript working in javascript.</s>

[Here is a sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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). Because for some reason Sketch won't let arrow keys being detected I've given it an automatic constant rotation. The effect is the same.

Comment: jsbin would be helpfull

Comment: I agree, but it's a nightmare trying to get paperjs to work in a regular javascript scope. Bear with me.

Comment: I always use paper in pure JavaScript mode - it's much easier to debug and is actually faster and paper-core.js is smaller than paper-full.js as well - it doesn't include a JavaScript parser. http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/

Comment: I've been looking at that page for a while. I am trying to inject paperscript into the global scope by doing `window.onload = function() {

 paper.install(window);

 paper.setup('canvas');

// code
}` but it's giving me an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'point' in { x: 0, y: 0 }{ x: 0, y: -7.5 }`

Comment: Ok this is giving me a headache. Here is a link to my own website where I've put it up: http://aronadler.com/asteroid/

Comment: Just added a sketch link.

Comment: No big deal. I don't do exactly what the tutorial shows actually. I just load paper-core.js and then do `paper.setup('canvas')`. What I do lose is the ability to use `+` (and other operators) on points; I have to do `point1.add(point2)`, etc. And I have to reference all paper functions and constructors with `paper` as a prefix, so `paper.Path.Line` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that path.bounds.center is not the center of the triangle. The default center for rotation is path.bounds.center. See [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/fVLRasMgFP0V8SUZZJIoe+noU3+gtI9dH9TcpSFOh7lljLF/ny4LJM4WRTiXc849Xv2iVr4B3dDjAKgvtKLatRGTF4sN2RILH2Qv8cIO0F2N9HtnPjtny1NT1xUJx7kiIuz64Tko+D0FzynEPYXIKGIu5h1KhLJ5mjxm/PhXaNiI3g2wc8b50AB5WhBJoVBG6qH49dere+96rw2UwVO5q21HpsEi+Irw2ErzHJfnuSLHFVluTMFee2PmgJqvoVjBwkM7hVfJo2mUtlvmj+6K3yDxJUncIIkFKTZMRqnSYat/w+48gJ3yziv8POVBDu+utzjSzen8/QM=). The red dots are bounds.center, the green rectangles are the bounds rectangle.

You want to rotate around the triangle center (technically centroid) which can be calculated by finding the point 2/3 of the way from a vertex to the midpoint of the opposite side.

Here's some code to calculate the centroid of your triangle:

```
function centroid(triangle) {
    var segments = triangle.segments;
    var vertex = segments[0].point;
    var opposite = segments[1].point - (segments[1].point - segments[2].point) / 2;
    var c = vertex + (opposite - vertex) * 2/3;
    return c;
}
```

And an updated [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) showing how the center doesn't move, relative to your triangle, as it is rotated, when calculating the centroid.

And I've updated your [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) to use the centroid rather than position. It now moves in a straight line.

Comment: Ok I understand, but that doesn't answer my problem, because I am explicitly telling it to rotate around a certain point. Therefore regardless of what its natural rotation point is, I am telling it to rotate around a certain point - namely `ship.shipPath.position` - so how is it possible that the rotation shifts the location of that very point?

Comment: Because that point is not the center of the triangle. Look at the sketch in my answer - rotating a triangle changes the center position. You don't want the center position because it's not the center of the triangle (in fact, as you rotate the triangle the size of the bounds rectangle changes too). I'll add a little code to calculate the centroid of a triangle. If you rotate around that position it will work.

Comment: Ahhh right right, ok I understand. Thanks @bmacnaughton!! And thanks for putting it in my code already :)